# NBug configuration questions

Tags: c#, winforms, nbug

Two questions regarding [NBug](https://github.com/soygul/NBug):

1. Can the NBug.config file be omitted if I'm having the configuration
   in the code like this:

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
         //NBug Crash Handling
         NBug.Settings.ReleaseMode = true;
         NBug.Settings.MiniDumpType = NBug.Enums.MiniDumpType.Normal;
         NBug.Settings.StopReportingAfter = 365;
         NBug.Settings.WriteLogToDisk = true;
         NBug.Settings.ExitApplicationImmediately = true;
         NBug.Settings.StoragePath = "WindowsTemp";

         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += NBug.Handler.UnhandledException;
         Application.ThreadException += NBug.Handler.ThreadException;
         [...]
   }
   ```
2. Why is this part of code never executed after a crash dump was created and the app restarted?

   ```
   public MainMenu()
   {
         InitializeComponent();

         //add handler on application load
         NBug.Settings.CustomSubmissionEvent += Settings_CustomSubmissionEvent;

         // Custom Submission Event handler
         void Settings_CustomSubmissionEvent(object sender, CustomSubmissionEventArgs e)
         {
             //your sumbmission code here...
             MessageBox.Show(e.FileName.ToString());
             //.....
             //tell NBug if submission was successfull or not
             e.Result = true;
         }
         [...]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Looks good, should work perfectly well.
2. If you compile from the source code, put a break point here and see what happens: https://github.com/soygul/NBug/blob/d48942b844f3ea2a6e90b993f4c63565e0426944/NBug/Core/Submission/Custom/Custom.cs#L44

If you're using nuget package, it's outdated so might not work.

Comment: I was using the nuGet package and switched to compiling it from GitHub now. The Breakpoint at the mentioned position is never hit. Also the Nbug.log is not created.

Comment: Comment out `ReleaseMode` and try again. You should see the log and the exception viewer (if there is any).

Comment: Already set `ReleaseMode` to false. But the log is not being created

Comment: I uploaded the code to GitHub in case you want to check https://github.com/roots84/DNS-Swapper

Comment: It looks good to me. Try the configurator tool. It has a test button where you can test sending reports. It might be a permission issue or similar. Using the tester should reveal if so.

Comment: But the configurator tool only uses the config-files (which I'm not using) and can't test custom destinations. With config file and email destination everything works just fine.

Comment: Alright I'm out of ideas at this point. This was never reported before and I don't use custom sub events so it could be a bug or a environment issue. Leave the question open in case someone else has an idea. You can open an issue at github if this turns out to be a reproducible bug.